# Generate a specified number of bytes key from a file

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I know that we can define the key explicitly using the below line. For 3des the key length should be 24 bytes, if I am not wrong.

```
Dim Newkey() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String("24 bytes enter here")
```

something like

```
Dim Newkey() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String("c:\temp\mykey.pem")
```

1. How do i make sure that the file gives back 24 bytes of data, for 3des encryption?
2. What/How do i generate such a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simply check the length of the array using NewKey.Length after decoding
2. Use `TripleDES.GenerateKey`, retrieve the key property. This will generate keys that should be compatible with TripleDES, then call `Converter.ToBase64String`

Please look up a tutorial of creating/reading textual files yourself, using FromBase64String on a file name won't work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.generatekey.aspx#Y0

Note that 16 byte keys may be used for TripleDES (ABA keys) as well as 24 byte (ABC) keys. Also note that there are weak keys in DES, and that keys include parity bits. Most implementations simply ignore the parity bits, but it is better to use a special key generation function to be sure they are set correctly.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Crypto
{
    public class KeyCreator
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {           
            String[] commandLineArgs = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            string decryptionKey = CreateKey(System.Convert.ToInt32(commandLineArgs[1]));
            string validationKey = CreateKey(System.Convert.ToInt32(commandLineArgs[2]));

            Console.WriteLine("<machineKey validationKey=\"{0}\" decryptionKey=\"{1}\" validation=\"SHA1\"/>", validationKey, decryptionKey);
        }   

        static String CreateKey(int numBytes) 
        {
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] buff = new byte[numBytes];

            rng.GetBytes(buff);
            return BytesToHexString(buff);
        }

        static String BytesToHexString(byte[] bytes) 
        {
            StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(64);

            for (int counter = 0; counter < bytes.Length; counter++) 
            {
                hexString.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", bytes[counter]));
            }
            return hexString.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i create a cer file, so that the raw bytes returned by it is 24? For the use as a key for 3des cryptoservice provider. Like TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\temp\whatever.cer");
cryptoProvider.Key = cert.PublicKey.Key.

Comment: Downvoted as it only partially covers the question and introduces hex out of nowhere, does not contain explanatory text or comments etc.